# How to calculate reverse scaling

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'am scaling a stage for example the scale value is decreasing like:

```
1
0.9
0.8
0.7
0.6
0.5
```

I want to make an inversion of this values, to increase the scale of the objects in the stage like:

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
```

what is the best way to do this? or is there a formula calculation for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just divide 1 on the scale

If you had 10, scaled it by 0.8 and want it back:

`size = 10 *`**`0.8`**`= 8`

and back:

`size = 8 *`**`(1 / 0.8)`**`= 10`

Just remember to do it in reverse order if you scale multiple times as scale is accumulated (scale x newScale).

```
0.9
0.8
0.7
0.6
0.5
```

to get it back to start:

```
1/0.5
1/0.6
1/0.7
1/0.8
1/0.9
```

A small [proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/QKfa9/).